# Manipulate relationship in data before returned response in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, orm, relationship

this is current response:

```
"id": 3,
"name": "hello",
"photo": {
    "id": 62,
    "address": "uploads/DKDH32kdsl29382dHW92387130.jpeg",
}
```

what I want is this:

```
"id": 3,
"name": "hello",
"photo": {
    "id": 62,
    "address": "http://mysite.domain/uploads/DKDH32kdsl29382dHW92387130.jpeg",
}
```

I mean I want to concat my site address to the **address** property of **photo** object

and finally this is my code:

```
return Model::select(
        'id',
        'name'
    )
    ->with('photo:id,address')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve your goal is using an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). With this feature you can access to the `address` parameter but instead of receving the default URI, you can tell Laravel to return a full URL.

```php
/**
 * Get the adress as URL.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
public function getAddressAttribute($value)
{
    return url($value);
}
```

Otherwise, if you're returning a JSON Response, you can do the same by using an [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources), which is a better solution since you won't mutate that value everytime you access it, but simply when it's required.

```php
class Model extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            // [...] other attributes
            'address' => url($this->address),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming you have a `Photo.php` model, you can use a `Accessor` to modify `address` to include your domain.

`Photo.php`:

```
class Photo extends Model {
  public function getFullAddressAttribute(){
    return "http://mysite.domain/".$this->address;
  }
}
```

Then, in your Controller:

```
return Model::select('id', 'name')
->with('photo:id,address,full_address')
->get();
```

Note: If `full_address` in `with()` causes an error, you can use `visible()` in combination with `appends()` to include it:

```
class Photo extends Model {
  protected $visible = ["id", "address", "full_address"]
  protected $appends = ["full_address"];

  public function getFullAddressAttribute(){ ... }
```

Then in your Controller:

```
return Model::select('id', 'name')
->with('photo')
->get();
```